On the first load of my site, why does it redirect the the page I access with XMLHttpRequest?
In the script at the bottom I get the result from /php/get/items-sold.php and put it into the div called items-list. It's not supposed to actually go to the page /php/get/item-sold.php, but on the FIRST load of my site it does - or it goes to the banner php file or the sidebar php file which are loaded in sidebar.js. But on subsequent loads it works entirely like it's supposed to.
I just tried putting the code that loads it in an event listener for DOMContentLoaded, as you can see in my code below, but it fixed nothing.
What could be causing this and how can I fix it?
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Crochet Store</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">
        <script>
            // to eliminate Flash Of Unstyled Content
            const loadingOverlay = document.createElement("div");
            loadingOverlay.id = "loading-overlay";
            loadingOverlay.innerHTML = "<div class='lds-ring'><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>";
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].prepend(loadingOverlay);
        </script>
        
        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Main -->
                    <div id="main">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <!-- Header -->
                            <!-- sidebar.js will fill this -->
                                <header id="header"><p id="js-disabled-warning">You have javascript disabled... the site needs javascript to function. Please enable javascript :(</p></header>

                            <!-- Banner -->
                            <!-- sidebar.js will fill this -->
                                <section id="banner"></section>

                            
                            <!-- Section -->
                                <section>
                                    <header class="major">
                                        <h2>Items I Sell:</h2>
                                    </header>
                                    <div id="items-list"></div>
                                </section>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- sidebar.js will fill this -->
                    <div id="sidebar"></div>

            </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/js/sidebar.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
            <script>
                function resizeBannerImg() {
                    const width = document.getElementById("banner-img").clientWidth;
                    $("banner-img").attr("height", width);
                }

                window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
                        const response = this.responseText;
                        $("#items-list").html(response);
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/php/get/items-sold.php");
                    xmlhttp.send();
                });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>


I just tried using window.onload = function() { //content here } instead of DOMContentLoaded - it's kinda hard to test if it worked since I already loaded the site once, but I guess I'll know tomorrow when I load it again?

Why would tomorrow make any difference? Is there some relationship to cookies there, or something like that? What about if you simply close your browser down and re-start it, or open it again in a private browsing session? Or just use another browser? All of those would start a new session which should simulate loading the site for the "first" time. I can't see anything in the code shown here which could cause what you describe, either. Are there any JS errors in the console when this occurs, or anything like that?

There are no errors. It doesn't make sense to me why this would be happening. I could try opening a private tab yeah, idk why I didn't think of that.

Well it didn't do the thing but I also tried loading it in a private tab without the new change and that also didn't do the thing - so I'm not sure how accurate that is

Look also at your Network tool - when you first open the browser, open the Network tool before you load the page. Then load the site, and you should see any network requests, including this erroneous navigation to a page which presumably is being done not as an XHR request (as it should be). It might give you a clue about where the request is coming from - maybe it's a redirect from the server, or triggered by some JS or something.

without the new change...what change are you referring to?

@Adyson The new change I'm referring to is changing window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded, function() { //content here })  to window.onload = function() { //XMLHttpRequest here }

Ok I see. So, revert that change and load it again in a private window. Then you'll know if that made any difference or not.

With or without the change, in the private window, neither are causing the problem. I tried deleting cookies and restarting my computer and the problem isn't happening again. I seriously think it only happens once a day the first time I view my website. This has been going on awhile and it doesn't make sense why it would only happen once a day but that's how it seems to work to me

I agree, this doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense. Very strange. Is the website being hosted locally on your computer, or on another server?
